# Why does the $num / ($num * 0 + 1) strip units?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

So I looked into the foundation for sites repo on git in order to get to know some advanced sass features and tripped over the strip-unit-function.
Basically it somehow strips the unit (px, em, rem) from a given input and just outputs the value.

```
@function strip-unit($num) {
    @return $num / ($num * 0 + 1);
}
```

But why does this work?
`(5px * 0 + 1)` returns 1px and `(5px * 1px)` returns 5px*px so how does 5px / (5px * 0 + 1) even compute? Is this some kind of hack or do I just fail to understand the logic?

Link to full repo
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/6.2-stable/scss/util/_unit.scss

**EDIT**
My question is not How to do it but why it works. Is it just a bug or some kind of hack does this follow any logical principle?
Why does stripping units by dividing work?

```
$number: 16px;
$without-unit: 16px / 1px;
@warn $without-unit; // 16
```

Comment: @cimmanon this question provides an answer on how to strip the unit from a value but my question was why this works.

Comment: The question itself explains part of it, the answerer explains the rest.

Comment: @cimmanon updated again, I hope the question is clearer now